# Парсер CURL: пустая страница при передаче любого POST запроса

Tags: php, парсер, curl, xmlparser

Методом проб и ошибок пытаюсь написать парсер на PHP + CURL сайта, построенного на Oracle BI. Ссылка на сайт - http://stat.customs.ru/analytics/saw.dll?Answers&NQuser=tsvt_ru&NQPassword=tsvt_ru (оффициальная таможенная статистика). Цель - переодическое получение таможенной статистики по разным продуктам.

С помощью панели разработчика Chrome на вкладке Network, как я понял, нужно передать через POST значение XML запроса (имя переменной - "ReportXML"). В ХML запросе можно указать инетересующий продукт (код ТН ВЭД).

Загвоздка в том, что если я не передаю POST запрос, то все работает - сервер выдает результат - "Невозможно выполнить запрос, т.к. он не содержит столбцов", что нормально, так как запроса пока нет (при желании можно даже указать ссылку на сохраненный отчет с **зафиксированным(!!!)** кодом ТН ВЭД и в результате сервер выдаст нужную таблицу). Но как только я начинаю передавать информацию через POST все рушится и выдается просто белый экран. Очень надеюсь на помощь, ломаю голову вторые сутки)

Заранее большое спасибо!

Код:

```
<?
//Нужная ссылка, куда нужно передать POST
//$url = "http://stat.customs.ru/analytics/saw.dll?Go&NQuser=tsvt_ru&NQPassword=tsvt_ru";

//Пример, таблицы
$url = "http://stat.customs.ru/analytics/saw.dll?Go&NQuser=tsvt_ru&NQPassword=tsvt_ru&ViewID=a%3aanswers%7er%3areport&SearchID=hj8i5kh3e72pflrq2oja7tc0kq&Style=oracle10&ViewState=rrm31r12r5ogd2r16340a1q9p6&viewName=compoundView%211&Action=Print";

$data = "Action=Print&Format=&SQL=&ReportEditor=&ViewEditor=&ViewPos=0&RtnToView=&ItemName=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B&Folder=%2Fusers%2Ftsvt_ru%2FSheva&Description=&ViewID=a%3Aanswers%7Er%3Areport%7Ev%3AcompoundView%211&ViewState=p2qpkguehhigrfqlq512s8vrce&RootViewID=a%3Aanswers%7Er%3Areport&UpdateAnswerTree=false&ReportXML=%3Csaw%3Areport+xmlns%3Asaw%3D%22com.siebel.analytics.web%2Freport%2Fv1%22+xmlns%3Axsd%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22+xmlns%3Asawx%3D%22com.siebel.analytics.web%2Fexpression%2Fv1%22+xmlVersion%3D%22200705140%22%3E%0D%0A+++%3Csaw%3Acriteria+subjectArea%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%A2%26quot%3B%22%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumns%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%A2%D0%9D+%D0%92%D0%AD%D0%94+%D0%95%D0%90%D0%AD%D0%A1%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%92%D0%AD%D0%94%2810+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%29%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c6%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c5%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c3%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c4%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB.+%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c0%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%2C+%D0%BA%D0%B3%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c1%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3Acolumn+formula%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%26quot%3B.%26quot%3B%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D0%94%D0%95%D0%98%26quot%3B%22+columnID%3D%22c2%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3Acolumns%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Csaw%3Afilter+subjectArea%3D%22%26quot%3B%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%A2%26quot%3B%22%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csawx%3Aexpr+xsi%3Atype%3D%22sawx%3Acomparison%22+op%3D%22equal%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++%3Csawx%3Aexpr+xsi%3Atype%3D%22sawx%3AsqlExpression%22%3E%22%D0%A2%D0%9D+%D0%92%D0%AD%D0%94+%D0%95%D0%90%D0%AD%D0%A1%22.%22%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%92%D0%AD%D0%94%2810+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%29%22%3C%2Fsawx%3Aexpr%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++%3Csawx%3Aexpr+xsi%3Atype%3D%22xsd%3Astring%22%3E2517101000-%D0%93%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9A%D0%90%2C+%D0%93%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%92%D0%98%D0%99%2C+%D0%A9%D0%95%D0%91%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%AC%3C%2Fsawx%3Aexpr%3E%3C%2Fsawx%3Aexpr%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3Afilter%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3Acriteria%3E%0D%0A+++%3Csaw%3Aviews+currentView%3D%220%22%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Csaw%3Aview+xsi%3Atype%3D%22saw%3AcompoundView%22+name%3D%22compoundView%211%22+rptViewVers%3D%22200510010%22%3E%0D%0A+++++++++%3Csaw%3AcvTable%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++%3Csaw%3AcvRow%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Csaw%3AcvCell+viewName%3D%22titleView%211%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++%3Csaw%3AdisplayFormat%2F%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3AcvCell%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3AcvRow%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++%3Csaw%3AcvRow%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Csaw%3AcvCell+viewName%3D%22tableView%211%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++%3Csaw%3AdisplayFormat%2F%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3AcvCell%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3AcvRow%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3AcvTable%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3Aview%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Csaw%3Aview+xsi%3Atype%3D%22saw%3AtitleView%22+name%3D%22titleView%211%22+rptViewVers%3D%22200510010%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Csaw%3Aview+xsi%3Atype%3D%22saw%3AtableView%22+name%3D%22tableView%211%22+rptViewVers%3D%22200510010%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3Aviews%3E%3C%2Fsaw%3Areport%3E";    


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$contents = curl_exec($curl);

echo $contents;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

POST запрос подразумевает собой передачу каких-либо параметров для получения какого-то результата.

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
"first"  => "John",
"last" => "Smith"
));

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```